# Change ImageView from another class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change `ImageView` image from another class, but it doesn't even see my `ImageView`

so I have an `ImageView`

```
ImageView card1 = findViewById(R.id.Card1);
```

In `MainActivity`. And I want to change it from another public class in the same package. How?

All I can imagine is just like I would do in `MainActivity` class

```
public class CardsFit {
    public void fit(){
        card1.setImageDrawable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add more code. How do you try to access image view from another class?

Comment: @dimsuz I did :)

Comment: You should learn how variables work in Java, especially what is variable scope. You can't just access variable declared in another class, this is not related to Android even. Or maybe your example is not complete.

Comment: As @dimsuz said, I think you should add more code, also what is card1 ? Where's come from ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - pass the result of `findViewById` via a constructor or some other method to an instance of the required class.

**It should be used carefully so as not to cause a memory leak when destroying an activity**

2 - pass the result of `findViewById` to a static method and apply all the necessary operations in this method.

I think the most appropriate way since the description of the question does not specify the reasons to keep the reference to the view

Comment: how to pass it? ^.^